# What is the point of using labels in javascript (label: stuff here) outside switches?

Tags: javascript

What is the point of using labels in javascript (label: stuff here) outside switches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use them as goto statements on `break` and `continue`, though admittedly you rarely see this in practice.  [You can find a few examples here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm).

Here's a quick one:

```
myLabel:
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  if(i==0) continue myLabel; //start over for some reason
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They're also useful in loops:

```
var x, y;

outer: for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    for (y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
       if (checkSomething(x, y)) {
           break outer;
       }
    }
}
```

...which breaks out of *both* loops if `checkSomething` returns true.

I've never actually coded one of those, I've always split the inner loop off to a function or similar, but you *can* do it that way. Some people consider it bad style, akin to `goto` (which JavaScript doesn't have).

Answer (score 0):

## Labels

#### can be very useful in controlling the flow of complex nested loops.

For ex:

There are two nested loops  where i want to stop iterating loops when a certain condition is met in the inner most loop.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    if (i === 2 && j === 2) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(`i = ${i}, j = ${j}`);
  }
}
```

This `break` in inner loop would only `break` in the inner loop but the would loop would still `continue` to run.

**Normal way** of fixing it

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    if (i === 2 && j === 2) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(`i = ${i}, j = ${j}`);
  }
  if (i === 2) {
    break;
  }
}
```

iterate to a certain level in inner loop and then `break` inner loop and then come out inner loop and break the outer loop with a second conditional.

**Better way**:

```js
outerLoop: for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
    if (i === 2 && j === 2) {
      break outerLoop;
    }
  }
}
```

The program first exit the inner loop (because that's the loop the program is currently executing), and then it exits the outer loop (because that's the loop the label `outerLoop` refers to).